# Confluence REST API create page with HTML content

Tags: ruby, confluence

I need to create a confluence page via the REST API. Creating a simple page is working, however if I try to add content to an existing HTML page I get http_response 400 (bad request).

Code snippet:

```
confluence_page_content = File.open("local_html_report", "r").read
json_data = {
  "body" => {
    "storage" => {
    "representation" => "storage",
    "value" => "#{confluence_page_content}"
    }
  },
  "space" => {
   "key" => "#{test_parameters["confluence_space"]}"
  },
  "title" => "TestPageFromChef",
  "type" => "page"
}.to_json
```

Answer (score 6):

Hy, solved it :)

Code snippet:

```
confluence_page_content = "<ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"html\">
  <ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[
  #{confluence_page_content}
  ]]></ac:plain-text-body>
  </ac:structured-macro>
  "
```